# echo json encode to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm looking through lot of example but I cannot figure out why I cannot use the array passed by my php code. I previously echo a single variable and it worked fine. But when I echo an array, there is no result.

```
$arr= array('comment_id' => 100, 'color' =>'green');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

in my jquery

```
$.ajax( 
 {
      url : $("#dataSaveOpinion" + parameter).data('url'),
      type: "POST",
      data : postData,
      success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
          {
             var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
             $(this).attr('data-url',$("#comment" + parameter).data('url')+result[0]);

          },
```

`result[0]`  is undefined

Comment: try using this approach: `objectName.key` or if its array, `objectName[index].key`

Comment: What does var_dump(json_encode($arr)) shows? Whats the content of data? Tried with a json lint?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP when you do a `json_encode()` to an associative array (key => value), the array gets converted to a `JSON Object` instead of a `JSON Array`, if you want to return a `JSON Array` you'll need to do one of the following:

Return an Array with an associative array inside:

```
$arr= array( array('comment_id' => 100, 'color' =>'green') );
echo json_encode($arr);
```

this will return:

```
[
  { comment_id: 100, color: 'green'  }
]
```

with this way `result[0]` in JavaScript will have the JSON object in the first position.

The other way (and the one I preferred) is to return an associative array with an array of arrays inside :P, well something like this:

```
$arr= array( 'comments' => array( array('comment_id' => 100, 'color' =>'green') ));
echo json_encode($arr);
```

this will return:

```
{
  comments: [
    { comment_id: 100, color: 'green'  }
  ]
}
```

and now you can refer to the result in a more expressive way, like this:

```
result.comments[0]
```

Please make sure to add this to your ajax request: `dataType: 'JSON'` so the code knows that it will be sending and receiving a valid `json`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Apparently, I did not need to use parseJson in my jquery. I added dataType:'json'.  And I used your first method.  And to get the result I did  data[0].comment_id

Comment: @trinocle if this was the right answer for your needs, could you please marked it as right answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `result['comment_id']`.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `$arr= array('comment_id' => 100, 'color' =>'green');` is an associative array mapping the key 'comment_id' to 100 and 'color' to 'green'. So, you have to retrieve the data using a key, in this case 'comment_id' or 'green.'

Try retrieving comment_id like this:

`result[comment_id]`

You can only use numeric indices if the array is a sequential array containing multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `dataType: 'json',` within your ajax function.

Also a JSON parse function within your response process

```
var result = JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the content-type before echo'ing back

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```